# java compile error depends on whether static variable name is qualified?

Tags: java, javac

Why does this java program not compile:

```
public class xx {
    public static final Object obj;
    static {
//        obj = null;       // this compiles
        xx.obj = null;      // this doesn't
    }
}
```

with this error:

```
$ javac xx.java
xx.java:5: cannot assign a value to final variable obj
        xx.obj = null;      // this doesn't
          ^
1 error
$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_33
```

when, if I replace `xx.obj = null` with `obj = null` (as alluded to in the comment) it does compile.

I thought the `xx.` class name prefix was more-or-less just syntax... is this a bug in the compiler or the language spec? :)

Comment: Probably a compiler bug (that has not bitten enough people so far to attract enough attention). Can anyone try on older and newer JDK versions? And also the Eclipse compiler ?

Answer (score 7):

When you do `xx.obj`, it means the class is already initialized. So `final obj` cannot be initialized again. This is a compile time error. Compiler could have checked that `obj` has not been initialized yet. It would be difficult to check that, but in theory it is possible.
But that is not how Java compiler works.

Comment: +1 This makes more sense then my answer, I noticed that you can access the class reference inside the static initializer, for instance for static methods or non-final static variables.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. This code is part of a static initializer, so class initialization is in progress when the code is run; java is designed to properly handle (what would otherwise be) recursive class initialization.

Comment: Still don't understand... what do you mean by: "When you do xx.obj, it means the class is already initialized"? Class initialization occurs at runtime; this is a compile-time question. Of course final fields can't be initialized twice, but that's not what's happening here. And compiler can indeed check it because the alternate version (`obj = null` instead of `xx.obj = null`) compiles just fine.

Comment: I also don't get this answer. The two code snippets are equivalent. This is very similar to using import vs typing a full class name. They result in the same byte code (have not checked). I cannot see how this can be anything else than a compiler bug.